# How to write forgetpassword manually for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I wrote a login system myself and for authentication I us `auth` and `User` model.

Now I want to wrote Reset Password,

I found `PasswordBroker` so I wrote a method in my controller:

```
public function forgetPassword(Request $request, PasswordBroker $password) {
        if (empty($request->session()->get('email'))) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        $response = $password->sendResetLink([$request->session()->get('email')], function($message)
        {
            $message->subject('Password Reset');
        });

    }
```

But when I trying to reset my password I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `0` = email@domain.com limit 1)
```

What should I do?

**UPDATE :**

my `users` migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: @MajAfy.are you sure you have users table which contain email field.because error message says Column not found

Comment: @vision Yes, I'm sure, because registration and login work fine

Comment: Is the email column named "0"?

Comment: @tam Absolutely No, the email field name is `email` I updated my question with `users` table migrate

Comment: Where is the code that actually resets the password, that is what we need to see

Comment: Goto `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php` and in `sendResetLink` method (line 55) do a **dd** with `$user` just below this line (line 60) `$user = $this->getUser($credentials);` So, your **dd** looks like this: `dd($user);`. Once you've got the result, edit your post and paste it there for us to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,

In `sendResetLink` we should pass `email` as `key` in first parameter,

so my code should change to this:

```
public function forgetPassword(Request $request, PasswordBroker $password) {
        if (empty($request->session()->get('email'))) {
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        $response = $password->sendResetLink(['email' => $request->session()->get('email')], function($message)
        {
            $message->subject('Password Reset');
        });

    }
```